# Android Application iFrame a Website

Tags: android, iframe, google-play

How can you create app in Android that iframes a website in Eclipse. What's the code for it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14):

I always preffer an example , like [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) :

First put in an xml layout this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in an Activity class , use this in onCreate:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView webview;
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: is that legal on Android? I mean, you cannot publish an app with iframes at least on iOS

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well (which is not sure at all), what you want to do is a WebApplication in android (using the SDK, hence your reference to eclipse).

Such applications behave like a custom web-browser. Basically it's a full screen [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) but you can customize virtually anything.

I think a good starting point is this [android developer tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

A View that displays web pages. This class is the basis upon which you can roll your own web browser or simply display some online content within your Activity. It uses the WebKit rendering engine to display web pages and includes methods to navigate forward and backward through a history, zoom in and out, perform text searches and more.

Answer (score 0):

using a webview do what u want!

in the layouts create a webview element like this:

```
<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/my_web_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

then in the activity u must initialize it and use webview  loadurl method!

if u want more information about this best place developers.android.com    and go to reference  section and select webview to see all available methods and usage guide!